# Android: ListView with TextView header problem

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a main activity like :

```
public class TestActivity  extends Activity{
    List<String> users;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.usersview);
        showList();

    }
    private void showList() {
        users=new ArrayList<String>();
        users.add("User1");
        users.add("User2");
        users.add("User3");

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
//      TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeMsg);
//      lv.addHeaderView(tv);
        lv.setAdapter( new ListArrAdapter(this, R.layout.userlist, users));
    }
```

ArrayAdapter :

```
public class ListArrAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String> users;
    private Context context;
    private int listlayout;

    public ListArrAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> users) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
        listlayout = textViewResourceId;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String userName = users.get(position);
        if (null == convertView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(listlayout, null);
        }
        TextView firstName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.firstNameTv);
        firstName.setText(userName);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

usersview layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:id="@+id/welcomeMsg"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

userlist layout for each items:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EEFFEE"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstNameTv"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is :

when i run this code only the welcome message is displayed(The items in list are not displayed).

when i uncomment the lines

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeMsg);
    lv.addHeaderView(tv);
```

in TestActivity, i get following exception

```
09-16 19:45:10.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

in line

```
lv.setAdapter( new ListArrAdapter(this, R.layout.userlist, users));
```

I want to display the list of users with a message-header on top. But i got these problem. Where is the problem and what is the solution.

Comment: The exception looking like due to "match_parent".
Try to use "wrap_content". Also instead of "fill_parent" use "wrap_content" in row xml

Comment: i tried that. still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your userview layout -

```
 <TextView
    android:text="@string/header"
    android:id="@+id/welcomeMsg"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
```

Change the layouts to wrap_content.

My guess is that the textview is covering the entire screen. therefore the list remains invisible.

For adding a header to your listview -

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Header Text");
listView.addHeaderView(tv);
```

Comment: i tried changing the layout. but not solution. the header text view is still showing "@+id/welcomeMsg" even after i did : TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Header Text");

Answer (score 0):

Refer this.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html.

It uses ListAdaptor with Icon , Textview. You can understand the reason behind not getting expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```